# Can you grant permission to a user to only have access to one file and not the entire site?

Tags: 2010

Can you grant permission to a user to only have access to one file and not the entire site?

Comment: Yes you can, by breaking permissions on the list item associated with the file and add permissions to your specific user

Answer (score 2):

here are steps:

- Go to that Document Library > go to the File > from the Actions Menu > select Manage Permissions
- from Ribion > click on Action Menu > click on stop inheriting permissions
- Now you can remove everybody and add the user directly which you want give permissions

**Note**
dont select a SharePoint group rather add the user directly. Otherwise user gets permission on other areas as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert said, you can do this pretty easily.

1. Find the document you want to limit permission on.
2. To the right of the name, click the twiddle to open the menu for the item.
3. Select **Manage Permissions** near the bottom of the menu.
4. In the ribbon, select **Stop Inheriting Permission**
5. Add or delete permissions as needed.

Hope this helps.